# strip formatting when copy paste email address into people picker input user field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, permissions, people-picker, copy-and-paste

I'd like to get rid formatting specifically, mailto html tags that comes along with email addresses copied directly from outlook when i paste it into the user input field.
It looks like its stripped out even when paste first in notepad, copy and then  paste but once i hit the resolve button, it spits out this

> `<A href="mailto:me@sample.com">me@sample.com</A>`

instead hence, an error saying no exact match was found...

I had tried using [this](http://sharepointpublishing.blogspot.com/2011/09/remove-format-when-copy-paste-in-rich.html) in the v4.master but nothing changed in this case.

Thanks.